# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I generate a JSON representation from type Car and then create a System.Object from that json. When I try to explicitly convert that object to type Car it shows an error "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid". Can anyone explain to me the reason?

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
[Serializable]
class Car
{
    public string type;
}
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{   
    void Start()
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.type = "BMW";

        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(car);
        System.Object @object = JsonUtility.FromJson<System.Object>(json);
        car = (Car)@object;
        Debug.Log(car.type);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are deserialising to `object` which cannot be cast to `Car`. Why not just directly deserialise to `Car`? Like this: `var car = JsonUtility.FromJson<Car>(json);`

Comment: I tried only to understand the deep cause of this error.

Comment: The cause is "you're not creating an instance of Car, so you can't cast to Car".

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do there is called Down/UpCasting.

In c# `object` is the parent class for all other types. So you can simply assign an inherited type (like in this case `Car` to an `object`) variable. This is called *Upcast*.

Then when trying to cast from a more generic to a more specific type (in your case `object` to `Car` this is called *Downcast*.

You only can directly downcast an `object` (which btw is simply a type keyword and alias for `System.Object`) to `Car` **if previously** this actually **was a `Car` reference** e.g.

```
Car car = new Car();
car.type = "BMW";

//string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(car);
//System.Object @object = JsonUtility.FromJson<System.Object>(json);
object @object = car;
car = (Car)@object;
Debug.Log(car.type);
```

would work since now `@object` actually still holds the information for a `Car` but *boxed* into an `object`.

---

You can not use

```
System.Object @object = JsonUtility.FromJson<System.Object>(json);
```

`System.Object` is not (de)serializable and makes absolutely no sense as target type here since the type `object` also holds no information about the fields you are wanting to deserialize. What you want is a `Car` not an `object`.

So what you *could* use is

```
// Here the Car reference returned by FromJson is BOXED into object
System.Object @object = JsonUtility.FromJson<Car>(json);
// Since @object is still a boxed Car value it is now UNBOXED from object to Car
car = (Car)@object;
```

---

However, why the whole casting **at all**? You really rather want to use

```
car = JsonUtility.FromJson<Car>(json);
```

Comment: You've got your terminology wrong here. *Boxing* is the process of wrapping a *value type* in an object, and *Unboxing* is its inverse. (See [Boxing and Unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)  in the C# programming guide.) Here, `Car` is not a value type; it is a reference type.  In other words, it is *already* an object.  So what you are actually doing in your example is just *Upcasting* and *Downcasting*.  But your main point still holds-- you can't downcast an object to `Car` if the object isn't really a `Car`.

Comment: (Boxes: `int`vs `Integer`)

Comment: @BrianRogers thanks for clearify this. In the autotranslated version I saw for unboxing it wasn't that clear that it applies only to value-types. Since the example was only between `object` and `int` I assumed it would be called the same for other types and classes as well.